# Flux through a section of a sphere

Tags: calculus

Given $\textbf{F} = \langle 0,x,0 \rangle $ and $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = a^2 $ where $ x\geq0, y\geq 0, z\geq0 $, calculate the flux through the surface

If I parameterize the surface as:

$$x=\cos u\sin v$$
$$y=a\sin u\sin v$$
$$z=a\cos v$$

with $0\leq u\leq \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $0\leq v\leq \frac{\pi}{2}$

I get a flux of $-a^3/3$

OR if I parameterize the surface as:

$$x=\cos u\cos v$$
$$y=a\sin u\cos v$$
$$z=a\sin v$$

with $0\leq u \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $-\frac{\pi}{2} \leq v \leq 0$

I get a flux of $a^3/3$

Why are they opposite in sign when the flux should be invariant under any coord system as a physical quantity? The answer in the book is positive.

Comment: What is flux? Presumably not something you solder with?

Comment: The second parametrization covers a different part of the sphere than the first.  $z \geq 0$ in the first, and $z\leq 0$ in the second.

Comment: I don't think so because in the first parameterization, v is measured from the vertical (z) axis, whereas in the second parameterization v is measured from the horizontal (y) axis, hence the negative $\pi/2$. Projecting the radius onto the x-y plane gives rsin(phi) and rcos(phi) respectively.

Comment: @coder: If $v = -\frac{\pi}{4}$ then $\sin(v) = -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$, so $z < 0$.  Compare http://wolfr.am/2CG3CH~V and http://wolfr.am/2CG8jEjb. Remember $u$ and $v$ are in different spaces than $x$, $y$, and $z$, so measuring one relative to the other doesn't jibe.

Comment: Minor comment: I changed the wording because this is an eighth of a sphere, not a quarter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flux depends on the designated normal direction.  From the other side of the surface the flux has the opposite sign.  For non-closed surfaces in space, we usually follow the convention that the “positive” normal vector is the one that points *upwards*, i.e., has positive $z$-component.

If you are computing the surface integral in the usual manner, you are probably forming the vector-valued function $\mathbf{r} = \left<a \cos(u) \sin(v),a\sin(u)\sin(v),a\cos(v)\right>$.  Then
$$
\iint_S \mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{S} = \iint_D \mathbf{F}(\mathbf{r}(u,v))\cdot (\mathbf{r}_u \times \mathbf{r}_v)\,dA
$$
where $S$ is the surface in question (an *eighth* of the sphere, BTW), and $D=[0,\pi/2]\times[0,\pi/2]$.  But notice
$$\mathbf{r}_u =\left<-a\sin(u)\sin(v),a\cos(u)\sin(v),0\right>$$
and
$$\mathbf{r}_v =\left<a \cos(u)\cos(v),a\sin(u)\cos(v),-a\sin(v)\right>$$
So
$$
\mathbf{r}_u\times\mathbf{r}_v= \left<-a^2\cos(u)\sin^2(v),-a^2\sin(u)\sin^2(v),-a^2 \sin(v)\cos(v)\right>
$$
Notice this vector points *downwards* on $S$.  So we take its opposite vector, or take the cross product in the opposite order, to correctly orient the surface.

Since
$$
\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{r}(u,v))\cdot (\mathbf{r}_v \times \mathbf{r}_u)
= \left<0,a \cos(u) \sin(v),0\right>\cdot\left<a^2\cos(u)\sin^2(v),a^2\sin(u)\sin^2(v),a^2 \sin(v)\cos(v)\right>
= a^3 \sin(u)\cos(u)\sin^3(v)
$$
The integral is equal to
$$
\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^{\pi/2} a^3 \sin(u)\cos(u)\sin^3(v)\,dv\,du = \frac{a^3}{3}
$$

Comment: Great analysis, but I think you did an eighth of a sphere.

Comment: Great, that makes sense to flip the normal vector outwards, thank you. However for the case where u=0 and v=0, the normal to the surface is zero. Should this be the case?

Comment: @coder: that's an astute observation.  You are correct to worry about places where $\mathbf{r}_u \times \mathbf{r}_v = \mathbf{0}$.  Luckily, these points constitute a set of measure zero in $D$, so the integral is unaffected.  Just like you can change a function of one variable at a point and the integral over an interval containing that point is unchanged.

Comment: @RonGordon: In the question the surface is described with relations as $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = a^2$, where $x\geq0$, $y\geq0$, and $z\geq0$.  OP calls that a quarter sphere but it seems like an eighth to me.